# jade template referencing an item with period

Tags: node.js, express, pug

my array is

```
{"Name.Value":"Joe", "Age.Value":65}
```

my jade is

```
input(type='text', id='Name' value='#{Name.Value}')
```

I am getting an error because it tries to read the property Value of the Name object. How can I fix that without changing my array keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any properties that aren't named as valid identifiers, such as those with periods, you have to use bracket notation to reach them.

```
obj['Name.Value']
```

For Jade templates, the `obj` you can use is called `locals`:

```
input(type='text', id='Name', value=locals['Name.Value'])
```

Note: The original snippet is currently missing a `,` after `id='Name'`.